# FRSDIAG / NTFRSUTL looking for servers which don't exist

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller, file-replication-services

I am using the FRSDIAG room(from tech-net) to do diagnosis on FRS replication. The issue is its tying to check the DC's which no ,longer exist . Error being "missing server reference for the server XXXX". Where is it getting those servers from? they don't exist in AD as objects. please let me know if any extra information is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use ADSIEdit, connect to the Default Naming Context.

DC=Domain > CN=System > CN=File Replication Service > CN=Domain System Volume (SYSVOL Share)

The nTFRSMember references are under that location, and each has an attribute "serverReference".

Comment: Found them , exactly at that location. they cant be found either in AD(Objects) or in sites. So i assume these are not cleaned up during a metadata cleanup. So please answer other question, can/should these be removed manually?  If they are left as it is, would it effect FRS to DFSr migration?

Comment: The stale ntfrs member and subscriber references should be removed during metadata cleanup.  If not, you would need to manually delete them.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, I manually deleted that reference. DC2 was upgraded ages ago from 2008R2 to 2016. looks like at some point this was left behind.